# Maximum number of pairs

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to find out the maximum number of pairs of 1's and 0's that can be found by just altering a single number in a given array.

For example:

If my input is `{1,0,0,1,0,0}`, here at index position `3` if I replace  `1` with `0` then I will get 4 pairs i.e the arrays becomes `{1,0,0,0,0,0}`, and the pairs are (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5).

But if I replace index position `0` from `1` to `0` then the array is `{0,0,0,1,0,0}` here I will get only 3 pairs i.e (0,1), (1,2), (4,5)

I need a program that returns maximum number of pairs possible for a given input array. In this case the program should give 4 as result.

Here the array contains only 1's and 0's.

Here is my program:

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program program = new Program();
        int[] a = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
        int response = program.calculate(a);
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    int calculate(int[] input) {
        if(input == null || input.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int length = input.length;
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
            if (input[i] == input[i + 1]) {
                result = result + 1;
            }
        }
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            if (i > 0) {
                if (input[i - 1] != input[i]) {
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    count = count - 1;
                }
            }

            if (i < length - 1) {
                if (input[i + 1] != input[i]) {
                    count = count + 1;
                } else {
                    count = count - 1;
                }
            }

            temp = Math.max(temp, count);
        }
        return result + temp;
    }
}
```

I was told the program is having some bugs but I was not able to find out where the issue is. I tried passing various values to this program but it is still working without issues. Can you please help me with some combination of inputs for which this program fails.

Comment: Appears to be maximum subarray problem. Kadane's algorithm should provide an answer.

Comment: int[] a = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; -> getting 8 as answer

Comment: @RajeevRanjan, maximum sub array is different, not related to my question. The 8 answer is correct, because if I replace position 7 then we get 8 pairs

Comment: ok.. I was looking for the longest sequence.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to be failing for

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}; -> 5 but not {0, 1}; -> 1
{ 1, 0, 1}; -> 2
{ 1, 1, 1}; -> 2
{ 1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}; -> 7
```